# How to execute a PowerShell script from Notepad++

Tags: powershell, cmd, notepad++

I am using Notepad++ to edit a PowerShell file and want to be able to execute that file from inside Notepad++.

How can I set that up?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It took me a little fiddling, but I finally got this working. (I am using version 1.0 but this should work in other versions as well.)

Notepad++ can be set up to run commands, and assign shortcuts to those commands, as follows:

From the menu, click **Run → Run**

Add the command

> C:\NotepadRun.bat "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"

Save the command, giving it a name and a key shortcut.

Below are the contents of the batch file. I named mine `NotepadRun.bat`, but you can name it whatever.

```
@echo off

GOTO %~sx1
:.ps1
 cd "%~d1%~p1"
 powershell.exe .\%~n1%~sx1 
 GOTO end
:.rb
 ruby "%~f1"
 GOTO end
:.php
 php "%~f1"
 GOTO end

:end

pause
```

As a note upgrading to Windows7 and  Powershell 2 I found some Issues with this and have updated to passing in an ExecutionPolicy to ensure I can run the script I am editing.

```
:.ps1
  cd "%~d1%~p1"
  powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File "%~n1%~sx1"
  GOTO end
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer - this makes it simple and aweseome!
Notepad++ has long been a favorite of mine and now it's even better.
(Language agnostic + Markdown support + great plugins)

Answer (score 4):

You can run a saved script from "Run" -> "Run" menu in Notepad++ with the following command:

```
powershell.exe -noexit -command . \"$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)\"
```

Comment: I do not remember why I used -command. But you're right, I might as well have used -file which would have made the full command cleaner.

Comment: Thought there was a reason for it, well, apparently not... :D

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using PowerShell ISE which comes as part of PowerShell and designed specifically for Powershell.

Comment: ps ise is good , but it locks the file and does not have nice npp features - search, highlight, etc

Answer (score 2):

See [Using Notepad++ to Compile and Run Java Programs](http://blog.sanaulla.info/2008/07/25/using-notepad-to-compile-and-run-java-programs/) and replace "javac" with "C:Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" (or your path to PowerShell). (Caveat: I'm not a Notepad++ user and haven't tried this.)

That said, I'd just use PowerShell ISE (installs with PowerShell) or one of the other dedicated PowerShell IDEs instead.

Comment: I agree... you can do it, but it's likely easier and more productive to just keep a powershell shell, an ise, and notepad++ open at all times.  I write and test on the command line, transfer and edit in notepad++, run the script on the command line, then, if need be, use the ISE to debug.  I rarely end up using the ISE though.

Comment: PowerShell is in the `PATH`, so no need to actually give the complete path, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the answers before:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -NoLogo -File "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
```

---

You can also add the `-NoExit` parameter to keep PowerShell from closing automatically:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -NoExit -NoLogo -File "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
```

---

**Note:** File has to be saved.