# open code file in powershell as text

Tags: powershell

I've got some .py and etc. file with code.

How to open it in powershell as text? I mean using `invoke-item` allows to open `.txt` in notepad but `code.py` will be executed using `python`.

So how to open it using powershell but in notepad at least(in notepad++ preferably)

Comment: you can open a file in notepad with `notepad.exe your_file.py`. If notepad++ is on your PATH then you should be able to do something very similar to open it with that application.

Answer (score 2):

Invoke-Item will open the application that has the file association for that file extension.

You could try Start-Process. I assume .py files will behave the same as .cs files but

`Invoke-Item a.cs` opens visual studio

`Start-Process notepad a.cs` opens notepad

But then again

`notepad a.cs` opens notepad as well.

If you're really keen to use `Invoke-Item` it appears its possible to update file associations using PowerShell - [change-file-asociations-via-powershell](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/3a7b4626-1662-4dc9-9a6a-b43af307fb7e/change-file-asociations-via-powershell)

Answer (score 0):

As already said just use:
notepad yourcode.py

As for notepad++, perhaps the best ways to do it are stated here:
[How to execute a PowerShell script from Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393529/how-to-execute-a-powershell-script-from-notepad)